# Returning subfolder names within dated folder

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, getdirectories

I'm trying to pull back a list of directories that sit inside a dated folder structure. Within each dated folder could be a number of 'Jobs' however i only want to return the name of the 1st level of folders

The below code gets to the right level of folder detail however the result displays the full path

```
 For Each Dir As String In System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories("c:\Working")
        Dim dirInfo As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Dir)
        For Each sDir As String In System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(dirInfo.ToString)
            Dim sdirInfo As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(sDir)
            chkImpExp.Items.Add(sDir)
        Next
    Next
```

This would display the following

[image: Folder Structure]

However i would just like to display the directory name to the right of the 3rd backslash (Westdale - 28023 - Cash+Spirit for example)

Hopefully this is enough information.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
' renamed Dir to d as Dir() is already a function in Microsoft.VisualBasic
For Each d In System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories("c:\Working")
    For Each sDir In System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(d)
        Dim di = New DirectoryInfo(sDir)
        chkImpExp.Items.Add(di.Name())
    Next
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
chkImpExp.Items.Add(sdirInfo.Name)
```